# React / Redux return object not what expected

Tags: react-redux

Probably something simple...I know I am missing something...
My user id is returning as the key instead of the value. This is a test to see what was returned from the api call.

actionCreator

```
import * as actions from "./types";
import axios from "axios";

export const userDashBoard = userId => dispatch => {
  axios.post("/api/authpages/dashboard", userId).then(user => {
    dispatch({
      type: actions.GET_PROFILE,
      payload: user.data
    });
  });
};
```

Reducer

```
import { GET_PROFILE, CLEAR_PROFILE } from "../actions/types";

const INITIAL = {};

export default (state = INITIAL, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_PROFILE:
      return { ...state, profileData: action.payload };
    case CLEAR_PROFILE:
      return { ...state, profile: "" };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

API

```
router.post("/dashboard", (req, res) => {
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

What I get from the return in Redux

[This should be an image of the redux result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZDR0.png)

I know that the api should return req.body.userId, but when I do that I get nothing. The only way I can get a response is to just call req.body...

Any help would be great...Thank you!

Comment: What's the response you get from the API when called from Postman?

Comment: The actual api through postman was the expected return....I deleted the route and went with a new strategy. Turns out this isnt really the way I wanted to handle this...im a newbie and forgot about the user object on the token..